# Close Dynamsoft Web Twain Popup

Tags: angular, angular13, dynamic-web-twain, dynamsoft

I am trying to implement Dynamsoft Web Twain in my Angular project. But there is no close button in the installation popup. How to add close button in the popup?

My Angular version is 13.3
Dynamsoft Webtwain version: 17.2.4
[Screenshot of popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xyp4.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to add the close button in `dynamsoft.webtwain.install.js`:

- Change the value of `closeButton` to `true` in `_this.DWT.ShowMessage(ObjString.join(''), { width: promptDlgWidth, headerStyle: 1, closeButton: true });`. By default, it is `false`.
- Add a button element based on current code.

  For example, add

  ```js
  ObjString.push('<div><a id="dwt-btn-close" 
  onclick="Dynamsoft.onClose()"><div class="dynamsoft-dwt-dlg- 
  button">Close</div></a></div>');
  ```

  below

  ```js
  ObjString.push(' onclick="Dynamsoft.DCP_DWT_onclickInstallButton()"> 
  <div class="dynamsoft-dwt-dlg-button">Download</div></a></div>');
  ```

  Then add the button click function

  ```js
  Dynamsoft.onClose = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('dynamsoft-dialog') 
  [0].style.display = 'none';
  }
  ```

  above

  ```js
  Dynamsoft.DCP_DWT_onclickInstallButton = function ()
  ```

  Now the popup window looks as follows:

  [image]

  You can click the close button to close the dialog. Due to `z-index`, the HTML elements under the popup dialog are not selectable. A tricky way is to modify `z-index` after hiding the popup dialog:

  ```js
  let divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].style.zIndex = -1;
    }
  ```
- Do not call `_this.DWT.ShowMessage(ObjString.join(''), { width: promptDlgWidth, headerStyle: 1, closeButton: true });`. Instead, use jQuery to create a custom dialog. For example:

  ```html
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"> 
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying 
  information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with 
  the &apos;x&apos; icon.</p>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: Thanks @yushulx. Able to close the dialog now. But not able to select any fields after closing popup. While Inspecting the page, class is shown as 'dynamsoft-backdrop'. So even though dynamsoft dialog box is closed, I guess the style class is still present there that of dynamsoft. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: @CJ you are right. It's caused by `z-index`. If you do not want to add a custom button, you just need to change the bool value of the `closeButton` in `_this.DWT.ShowMessage(ObjString.join(''), { width: promptDlgWidth, headerStyle: 1, closeButton: true });`

Comment: Is it possible to include this functionality without changing dynamsoft.webtwain.install.js ?

Comment: @CJ You can override the function by re-declaring it in your html page.